# SQL rounding time to nearest 30 minutes

Tags: sql

I am using this SQL Query:

```
SELECT ROUND((hours*60+minutes)/30) from table
```

which calculates the number 30 minutes segments

if i have 2 hours, 10 minutes this is returning `30_minute_segments = '4'` however i would like it to show 5 as the `10 minutes` should count as 30 minutes.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use `CEIL` instead of `ROUND`.  `CEIL` will round up.

```
SELECT CEIL((hours*60+minutes)/30) from table
```

I just realized that I assumed you were using Oracle.  But you didn't specify your database.

For SQL Server, the equivalent function is `CEILING()`.  Most databases have something similar.  (Note: if using SQL Server, be mindful of @Chizzle's comment below.)

Comment: Why the heck does `SELECT CEILING( ( 2 * 60 + 10 )  / 30 )` still return 4 in SQL Server?? Is it because of integer datatype?

Comment: @Chizzle, I'm not sure.  Doesn't sound right, but I don't have a SQL Server instance in front of me.  You might want to ask a new question of your own since this thread is focused on charlie's issue only.

Comment: @Marc I just figured it out myself and it maybe we worth noting in your answer, by changing one of the numbers to a decimal it get's the expected results of that formula:`SELECT CEILING( ( 2.0 * 60 + 10 )  / 30 )` = `5` while  `SELECT CEILING( ( 2 * 60 + 10 ) / 30 )` returns `4`

Comment: Interesting.  Oracle does not do that.  I added a reference about your findings, so thanks!